# Adding new attribute to static block(cms/block)

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, static-block

Greetings StackExchange.

I'm not quite sure whether this has been answered before or not. I have done a fair amount of blog / thread searching on this problem/topic.

Is there a way to add a custom attribute to Static Blocks? For example it is possible via. the backend to create a new attribute and add it to a attribute set for products. For categories it has to be done with a small module, a install script and so on.

I have not come across a way of doing this to either of CMS pages or static blocks.

Can somebody help me getting in the right direction?

WHAT I WANT: 
A dropdown value/attribute for each unique static block, eg "Include, Exclude, Ignore", in the same area as "Status".

[image: Static block]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you need to overwrite this class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Block_Edit_Form`. This class is used to add fieldsets and fields for `cms_block`. Take a look on the `_prepareForm()` method inside it.

If you put this code, just after `Title` field,

```
    $fieldset->addField('sub_title', 'text', array(
        'name'      => 'sub_title',
        'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Sub Title'),
        'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Sub Title'),
        'required'  => true,
    ));
```

you can see your `sub-title` text field in static blocks. However **Do not edit a core file directly**. You need to write a custom module that should overwrite this class. Your Module config file should contain this code

File : `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml`

```
<config> 
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                     <cms_block_edit_form>Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Cms_Block_Edit_Form</cms_block_edit_form>
                </rewrite>        
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

This will allow you to rewrite the class. What you need to do now is define the rewrite class now and in there you need to rewrite `_prepareForm()`. It should some what look like this.

Location :  `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Cms/Block/Edit/Form.php`

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Cms_Block_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Block_Edit_Form {

     protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        //put all the code inside parent class here 
        //then place the below content in appropriate place

        $fieldset->addField('sub_title', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'sub_title',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Sub Title'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Sub Title'),
            'required'  => true,
        ));
        return parent::_prepareForm();

    }
}
```

Try based on this idea

### EDIT

Please note, it will allow you to put new field in `cms > block`, howver to save this, you need to define model for your module. You have two options. Add a new field to save your new field in Cms > Block table or create your own table and store this value in that field along with the referene to cms >block table. This is out of box  and you should implement it your own way.

Comment: Thanks alot! 

I've added a table to the cms_block table.